# catch an html element with a particular attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can get the following input field from a web page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="CXoeqwAw2LGN5IXGzswnKj2XRu6gCdlfuIAzf3TFH5PhHlRMTaBjVNqIeY3OLaed">
```

I can do this using the following code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://dnsdumpster.com'
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8' # Optional: requests infers this internally
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    input = soup.find_all('input')
    csrfmiddlewaretoken_raw = str(input[0])
    print(csrfmiddlewaretoken_raw)
```

But, is there a simpler way, using which I can get the value of the "input" tag that has the "name" attribute of csrfmiddlewaretoken. I am just interested in the token value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to use `input` a variable name.

Just pass it in as a dictionary.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://dnsdumpster.com'
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8' # Optional: requests infers this internally
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    token = soup.find('input',{'name':'csrfmiddlewaretoken'})
    print(token['value'])
```